# CSS Bootstrap row separation using border top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please, consder the following **snippet**:

```css
.box {
  color: #000;
}
.pt {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.element {
  border-top: 3px solid #ff0000;
}
.p-20{
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="p-20">
  <!-- REPEATING ELEMENT -->
  <div class="row element">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="box">
        ELEMENT
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="box">
        ELEMENT
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- REPEATING ELEMENT -->
  <div class="row element">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="box">
        ELEMENT
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="box">
        ELEMENT
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- REPEATING ELEMENT -->
  <div class="row element">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="box">
        ELEMENT
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="box">
        ELEMENT
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are three sample rows seperated by a red border (border-top). As you may notice, **the border is not perfectly aligned to the text**. There is a 15px disalignement due to bootstrap margins.

**What is the most simple way to align the border to the text using bootstrap?**

Please consider that the two text elements in each row will be displayed one under the other on mobile screens. In this case there should be only one border between each row as in the example.

Thanks.

Comment: You might need to put it into a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it has to do with the `padding` of the `div` with class `col-` in bootstrap.

you can add :

```
.col-sm-6 {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
}
```

```css
.box {
  color: #000;
}
.pt {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.element {
  border-top: 3px solid #ff0000;
}
.p-20{
  padding:20px;
}
.col-sm-6 {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="p-20">
  <!-- REPEATING ELEMENT -->
  <div class="row element">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="box">
        ELEMENT
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="box">
        ELEMENT
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- REPEATING ELEMENT -->
  <div class="row element">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="box">
        ELEMENT
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="box">
        ELEMENT
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- REPEATING ELEMENT -->
  <div class="row element">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="box">
        ELEMENT
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="box">
        ELEMENT
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve this:

- remove the .row class from .element divs
- leave the .row divs as is but remove the .element. Then enclose the col-sm-6 divs in a **new** .element div **inside** the .row